# MVC4 get table data from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I get the **data** which is **bottom left hand side** of the **image** **from view to controller** when I **press** to **submit** button  ?

Link for [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6yOF.jpg)

```html
 public ActionResult EnterInformation1()
        {
           // the ??? is the data from the view;
           TempData['abc'] = ???
     
           return RedirectToAction("Paper");
        }
```

I did look up reference before I ask.thanks

Comment: Include the code in the question not a link. What is your question?

Comment: Which part of _"Include the code in the question not a link"_ do you not understand?

Comment: I want to include to code, but I don't have enough reputation to do that

Comment: Just edit you question and include the code. Reputation has got nothing to do with it - your can type in whatever you want.

Comment: thanks, sorry must be because I was inserting a image so it say I don't have enough reputation not the code.

Comment: Your `EnterInformation1()` method does not even have  a parameter to accept any data from the view (is it even a post method?) and what is the model your posting back? and what do you want to do with it? and how do you render the controls for the model in the view? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for giving patience , I will read through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data from view to controller all you need is to do next step:
1) Send data from controller to view. For example you want to display the content of a model wich is List

```
public ActionResult ShowList()
{
   List<string> lst = new List<string>() {"1", "2", "3", ,"4"};
   return View("MyListView", lst);
}
```

2) Display this data on the View using html helpers with postfix "for" (for example, textBoxFor, hiddenFor, EditorFor, DisplayFor...) and place them inside form tag

```
    @model List<string> 

   <form action="GetDataFromView" method="post">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>some header</th>
      <tr>
       @foreach (var item in Model) {
       <tr>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(m=> item)
           </td>
       </tr>
       }
    </table>
    </form>
```

3) Write Method in controller wich will get these data

```
public ActionResult GetDataFromView(List<string> model)
{
  //do what you want with data sended from view to controller
  // which stored in parameter model
  return View("someView");
}
```

Comment: If I don't need to display the content of a model . How am I going to get the data.

Comment: In this case you should use HiddenFor() instead of DisplayFor()